# CakePHP+NetBeansによるクラサバアプリのデバッグ

Tags: php, cakephp, debugging, netbeans

以下の環境で開発しています。 
開発用端末：Windows 7 + NetBeans8 
サーバ：Linux + (X + NetBeans8) + Apache + CakePHP

ブラウザから URL 経由でアプリを呼び出す形式、およびサーバ側で CLI 起動する形式(cake console)は、なんとか NetBeans でデバッグできるようになりました。

今度は、別の C# で書かれた既存のクライアントアプリがあって、これが上記サーバの URL へデータを POST した後の流れをデバッグできないかと思っています。特に NetBeans にはこだわりませんが、このような環境で、サーバ側でステップ実行することができないでしょうか。

> 太古の昔に C で開発していた頃は、gdb で実行中のプロセスにアタッチしてほげほげとやっていたような、、、

また、現在便宜的に、固定値を POST するだけの簡単な CLI アプリを PHP で書いて動かしたりしていますが、このような環境で CakePHP の Internal Error が出た日には、エラー画面を作る生 HTML がたっぷりコンソール上に表示されて、あまり嬉しくありません。これについても何か対策がありましたらアドバイスをお願いします。

Comment: 後者については、独立した CLI から叩くからダメなんですね。
テストしたいコントローラに、CLI と同じ動作をするフォームを出力するメソッドを書いて、NetBeans から URL 指定でそのメソッドを起動するようにしたらデバッグできました。

前者についても、引き続き情報をお待ちしております。

（タグとして NetBeans を追加していただけるとありがたいです）

Comment: PHP のバージョンは幾つでしょうか？ PHP 5.6 であれば標準で `phpdbg` というデバッガがついてきて、ステップ実行が可能になります。[phpdbg](http://phpdbg.com) `phpdbg` の表示上は The debugging platform for PHP5.4+` となっているので、一応 PHP5.4 でも対応しているようです。

Comment: phpdbg 、以前聞いたことありましたがスルーしてました。早速使ってみましたが、なぜか何をやってもSEGVるので、phpdbg自体を追跡中です。昔話で書いたgdbを、まさか使うことになろうとはｗ ちなみに環境はCentOS7+PHP 5.6.6です。

Comment: php のリポジトリは普段から https://webtatic.com/ を使わせてもらってるのですが、このうち phpdbg だけ最新版でビルドし直したら SEGV はなくなりました。動作確認はこれからです。